# URL to SEO friendly urls Laravel route

Tags: laravel-8

Need to make my urls to friendly ones in laravel.   How will i do it in routes?

https://www.example.com/?d=PH -> https://www.example.com/ph

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.